# Remove HTTP headers from a raw response

Tags: c#, regex, httpresponse, http-headers

Let's say we make a request to a URL and get back the raw response, like this:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Date: Wed, 28 Apr 2010 14:39:13 GMT
>   Expires: -1
>   Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
>   Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=e2bca72563dfffcc:TM=1272465553:LM=1272465553:S=ZN2zv8oxlFPT1BJG; expires=Fri, 27-Apr-2012 14:39:13 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.co.uk
>   Server: gws
>   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
>   Connection: close

```
<!doctype html><html><head>...</head><body>...</body></html>
```

What would be the best way to remove the HTTP headers from the response in C#? With regexes? Parsing it into some kind of HTTPResponse object and using only the body?

EDIT:

I'm using SOCKS to make the request; that's why I get the raw response.

Comment: not a C# guy, so I'm only going to comment :) I'm pretty sure some of this .NET stuff would have a facility for doing so.  Just guessing though :)

Comment: How are you making the request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Headers and body are separated by empty line. it is really easier to do it without RE. Just search for first empty line.

Comment: what example? int i = 0; foreach (string s in response) if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) break; else i++;

Comment: I came up with this:
if (responseString.IndexOf("HTTP/1.1 200 OK") > -1)
responseString = responseString.Substring(responseString.IndexOf("\r\n\r\n"));

Answer (score 1):

If you use [HttpWebrequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class you get an [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6877ayz6.aspx) object returned which in turn contains a collection of [Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.headers.aspx). You can then remove them, parse them or do whatever you wish with them.

Comment: I wish .NET had something like that for SOCKS. :(

Answer (score 1):

Note that using the substring method will leave you with a leading carriage return. I used this:

```
 string HTTPHeaderDelimiter = "\r\n\r\n";
 if (RawHTTPResponse.IndexOf("HTTP/1.1 200 OK") > -1)
    {
       HTTPPayload = RawHTTPResponse.Substring(RawHTTPResponse.IndexOf(HTTPHeaderDelimiter)+HTTPHeaderDelimiter.Length);
    }
    else
    {
       return;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was doing something like this already, but you've formatted it a bit nicer.